# pulling posts from different categories on to different pages (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

i have this code:

```
<?php
$catPost = get_posts(get_cat_ID("music")); //change this
foreach ($catPost as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
 <div>
    <li id="product_thumbnails">
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <p><?php
  $thumbnail_id=get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
  preg_match ('/src="(.*)" class/',$thumbnail_id,$link);
  ?>
```

which pulls all posts from "MUSIC" category onto specific page.
I have around 15 pages and i want onto each one of them to pull different category like "Movies, Sports etc".
Do i have to create 15 templates and into each one of them change this line:

```
$catPost = get_posts(get_cat_ID("music")); //change this
```

to for example:

```
$catPost = get_posts(get_cat_ID("movies")); //change this
```

or there is a cleaner way to do it, is it possible at all?
I am using theme twenty twelve.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is create your fifteen pages, make one template with the below code, and just add a `custom field`, maybe something like `this_page_cat` (you can name it anything) to all fifteen pages.  so for your fifteen pages you would have:

```
page 1: this_page_cat = music
page 2: this_page_cat = books
page 3: this_page_cat = movies
...
```

then just change your code in the template to

```
<?php
$custom_fields = get_post_custom(); //gets custom fields for this page
$my_custom_field = $custom_fields['this_page_cat']; //get fields named 'this_page_cat'
$catPost = get_posts('category=' . get_cat_ID($my_custom_field[0])); //get_post_custom() returns multidimensional array so you need to access the index you want
foreach ($catPost as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
<div>
<li id="product_thumbnails">
  <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <p><?php
 $thumbnail_id=get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
 preg_match ('/src="(.*)" class/',$thumbnail_id,$link);
endforeach;
?>
```

apply that template to all fifteen pages and you should be good.  Custom fields are one of the best parts of WP, here is [more info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) on them.  The other answer would probably work but this is much more extensible solution.

Comment: This looks good, but when tested i get blank page. I have created custom filed named "music" for example.Then edited code(cope/paste) what you wrote. And i get blank page.
Do i need to edit the code you wrote?

Comment: the code should be ok.  just to clarify, did you name the field `music` or was that the value?  the name should be `this_page_cat` and the value should be `music`.  if that is what you did, could you do a `var_dump($my_custom_field);` and `var_dump($custom_fields);` and post the results?

Comment: yes this_page_cat and value are ok. dont know how to "dump', so i just copy paste that in php?
(sorry i am really a noob in php)

Comment: yeah, `var_dump()` is a built-in php function that is INCREDIBLY helpful. it displays the contents of whatever you pass it, so in this case it will show us what is in `$my_custom_field` and `$custom_fields`, which will help debug your blank screen

Comment: i added it to end of the code nad i still get blank page only:
`<li class="product_thumbnails">
  <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <p><?php
 $thumbnail_id=get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
 preg_match ('/src="(.*)" class/',$thumbnail_id,$link);
var_dump($my_custom_field);
 var_dump($custom_fields);
 ?>`

Comment: do you have a link i can look at for the page? the `var_dump` should have SOME output even if it is just `null`...

Comment: seeing as there is basically no html output to the page, your php is erroring somewhere. there should be an `error_log` on your server, what does that say? also i think you forgot an `endforeach`, i updated  my answer with that aswell

Comment: "endforeach" was the problem , thanks!!
the thing is that it still pulls all posts form all categories.
It should pull only first 2 named "fiting"

Comment: ok yeah, so [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) has a special syntax for its arguments.  i edited my answer again

Comment: Works PERFECT!!! I don't know how can i thank you much! I don't think i can vote up because i just registered. :)

Comment: No problem, it was a pleasure, i remember how much trouble i had when i first started with WP and php so i totally understand.  The [Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) and the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php) are the two most valuable resources there are, read them wisely and good luck coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can load the categories you want to see into an array.
You retrieve these from a PHP Get or switch etc?

```
$poststoretrieve = array ('category' => '1,2,3,4,5,6'));
$postsloop = get_posts($poststoretrieve;

foreach ($postsloop as $onepost){
    //loop stuff here
}
```

More info see http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts